# Android volley DefaultRetryPolicy do not work as intended

Tags: android, android-volley

So, I have this Volley PUT request:

```
private boolean syncCall(JSONObject jsonObject, final VolleyCallback
        callback) {

    final ProgressDialog progDailog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    final Boolean[] success = {false};

    progDailog.setMessage("...");
    progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    progDailog.setCancelable(false);
    progDailog.show();

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new HurlStack());

    final String token = prefs.getString("token", null);

    String URL = Constants.getUrlSync();
    String param1 = String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("pmp", 1));
    String param2 = String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("ei", 1));

    URL = URL.replace("[x]", param1);
    URL = URL.replace("[y]", param2);

    //pegar id pmp e IE corretas
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request
            .Method.PUT, URL, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response + "");
                    success[0] = true;
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    callback.onFailure(error);
                    tokenFailure(error);
                    success[0] = false;
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws
                AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Token", token);

            return headers;
        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);


    queue.add(jsObjRequest);

    return success[0];
}
```

My problem is that I send a very large `JSON`, so the default timeout of 5 seconds is not enough. So, I tried to increase the timeout to 30 seconds and messing with the `DefaultRetryPolicy` to increase the number of retries.

The thing is, it keeps `timeouting` in 5s and it doesn't even retry once!

Do I have to have a listener or a callback for the retries ? I'm doing something wrong with the `DefaultRetryPolicy` ? Please help, this issue is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to use the DefaultRetryPolicy?

Because you could define your own.

Instead of this:

```
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,     
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,     
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
```

Try this:

```
jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() { 
            // Here goes the new timeout
            return mySeconds; 
        }
        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() { 
            // The max number of attempts
            return myAttempts; 
        }
        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
            // Here you could check if the retry count has gotten
            // To the max number, and if so, send a VolleyError msg
            // or something    
        }
    });
```

Comment: I create my own policy. The request doesn't terminate(timeout 10, retry 3). I use string request.

Comment: @user2362956 Open a new question with your code and explaining your attempts and results, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why the retry time doesn't work on your code, I did find a similar issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80786) though.

Instead, I can tell you some things that I don't believe to be ok in your code and suggest you to adopt my model of Volley use.

First of all, you're creating a new request queue for every request you're making. That's not cool, you should have a RequestManager singleton that holds one request queue and use that.

Second of all, I don't know if this is what affects the retry time, I have a base request class and set the retry time in the constructor. Then, I extend this class whenever I have to implement a new type of request. Then, I create an instance of the request, set the callbacks, and pass it to the request manager. The request manager adds it to the one request queue I was talking about.

More over, if you don't already, I suggest you use the Gson library to parse the JSON objects.

This is my base request class I'm using:

```
/**
* Created by Daniel on 2/6/2016.
*/
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

protected Context context;
protected final Gson gson = new Gson();
protected final Class<T> clazz;
protected final TypeToken typeToken;
protected Map<String, String> headers;
protected Map<String, String> params;
protected final Response.Listener<T> listener;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url   URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(final Context context, final int requestMethod, String url, Class<T> clazz, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.context = context;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.headers = new HashMap<>();
    typeToken = null;
    setRetryPolicy();
}

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url       URL of the request to make
 * @param typeToken Relevant typeToken object, for Gson's reflection
 */
public GsonRequest(final Context context, final int requestMethod, String url, TypeToken typeToken, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.context = context;
    this.typeToken = typeToken;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.headers = new HashMap<>();
    clazz = null;
    setRetryPolicy();
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params != null ? params : super.getParams();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    //TODO add headers here
    return headers;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        if (clazz != null) {
            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } else {
            return Response.success((T) gson.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType()), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

protected void setRetryPolicy() {
    //TODO set your retry policy here
    setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
}
}`enter code here`
```

This works like a charm for me. Hope it helps, if you need any further help, contact me