# Volley request setTimeout

Tags: android, http, networking, android-volley

I try to set timeout for a request. I know that I set request policy.

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10,
    3,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

My request is taken 500ms on postman. Upper code sets timeout and the request triggers error. But it doesn't retry.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506237/android-volley-defaultretrypolicy-do-not-work-as-intended) says that define your own policy. The request doesn't terminate.

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
                @Override
                public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                    // Here goes the new timeout
                    return 10;
                }
                @Override
                public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                    // The max number of attempts
                    return 3;
                }
                @Override
                public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
                }
});
```

**EDIT** I want to get timeout error and try again the given number of retry count.

`retry` method fires continuously for small number(forexample 100 ms, 200 ms)

Comment: You said your request take 500ms for completion then how can you get it with intial time only 10.

Comment: I want to see timeout error.

Comment: Volley request setTimeout default 5 second

Comment: I want to get timeout error. And I want to try again with the number of retry count.

Comment: see the answer of @VinceStyling in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676738/retry-request-onerrorresponse-android-volley) link that he defines new JsonObjectRequest.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase time like

```
return 3*60*1000;
```

Here it is time out within three minutes. I have use bellow like which is working for me

```
public VoleyErrorHandling(StringRequest stringRequest){
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            // Here goes the new timeout
            return 5*60*1000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            // The max number of attempts
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
            // Here you could check if the retry count has gotten
            // To the max number, and if so, send a VolleyError msg
            // or something
            //Log.d("err", error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Call it before like

```
//Begin set Time Out
    new VoleyErrorHandling(stringRequest);
    //End set Time out
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I don't want to increase the timeout.  I want to get timeout error and try again the given number of retry count.

Answer (score 0):

```
 If your request taking 500ms time on postman so you can set timeout time in your code like this.

 stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(600,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

 Above 600 ---> is in milisecond
 if you set 6000 ---> will be 6 second
 if you set 60000 ---> will be 60 seconds or 1 minute.

 So set according to your choice..
```